# How to begin ethical investing?

Tags: investing, starting-out-investing, investment-strategies, european-union, ethical-investing

So, I would like to start investing for the long-haul (10 - 15 years, expecting 4% ROI). When I looked up the top Broad European Stock Funds, I get an index that includes these holdings:

- Nestle SA
- British American Tobacco PLC
- Royal Dutch Shell PLC Class A
- BP PLC

These are not the sort of companies I want to support because I personally dislike their business. How would I go about getting a similar index that covers solar/renewable energy companies, companies that are performing R&D on improving quality of life etc.

Comment: My gut feeling is that you should remove the paragraph after your list of companies (if not the list itself)... _which_ companies you don't want to invest in and _why_ isn't really material to the core question which is how do I avoid certain companies when investing in "funds". To which the answer can only be look for funds which have an ethical policy that disbars certain companies or market-sectors and which matches your own view of what's right or wrong.

Comment: @TripeHound: It is relevant. There are "ethical" funds which have a policy of avoiding certain classes of investments, but these only make sense if their idea of ethics is aligned with your. As an  example, funds that avoid nuclear energy are unethical _in my opinion_ as nuclear energy is necessary now to reduce greenhouse gases.

Comment: @MSalters My point is: PF&M doesn't do recommendations, so someone listing _their personal ethics_ and asking for fund suggestions would be off-topic. The only way (as I see it, and I accept I'm a relative newcomer) to keep it on-topic is to ask a more generic "_How do I select funds if I have [unspecified] ethical concerns?_". To which the (somewhat trite) answer is "_Look for funds whose investment policies align with your personal ethics_".

Comment: I approved your edit